# How to self-destruct application?

Tags: android, uninstallation

I have pretty unusual task: customer would like to have application which can be self-destructed. Like with one **BIG RED MAGIC** button, pressing on which should completely destroy (possibly uninstall) application including any DBs, files, traces in logs and so on.

Does someone knows is it really possible, if yes - how?

Comment: Try one of [these](http://habitsforsmartpeople.com/content/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Use-the-right-hammer-for-the-job.jpg)

Comment: @MrE I think the customer rather wants something like [this](http://www.koozai.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/magic-button.png)

Comment: Beside jokes - is it possible?

Comment: You can delete application files (just enumerate app directory and delete everything) and files on sdcard (files that your app created/etc.). Uninstalling is a different beast altogether. non system apps cannot do that AFAIK (starting from android 2.0?).

Comment: these should be written as answers...

Comment: @Audrius please put in as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can purge application files by enumerating app directory and deleting everything in there plus removing your application files on SD card. Uninstalling application itself is a different beast altogether. Non system apps cannot do that AFAIK (starting from android 2.0?).